# WebMatrix Giving 404 with UrlRouting

Tags: webmatrix

I've been trying to follow these two links on how WebMatrix does URL Routing
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/165/WebMatrix-URLs-UrlData-and-Routing-for-SEO
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior

From my understanding, for something like http://localhost:44893/a/xyz

WebMatrix will first for a file name /a/xyz.cshtml and if that isn't found then it will check for /a.cshtml and if that isn't found then it will check for /a/default.cshtml

I created an empty site in WebMatrix 2 Beta ( 3/5 Refresh ). I created a folder name a and created a default.cshtml file inside.

If I go to http://localhost:44893/a, I'll get the default page but if I go to http://localhost:44893/a/xyz, I'll get

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Module    IIS Web Core 
Notification    MapRequestHandler 
Handler    StaticFile 
Error Code    0x80070002 
Requested URL    http://localhost:44893/a/xyz 
Physical Path    C:\Code\Test\a\xyz 
Logon Method    Anonymous 
Logon User    Anonymous

Is there anything that I'm missing to setup this up?

Answer (score 1):

You missed this part of the article:

> If no matches are found during the search for files, Web Pages will
>   attempt to locate a default document instead. The two default
>   documents which work are default.cshtml and index.cshtml in that
>   order. However, this search is performed once, and assumes that the
>   URL is entirely a file path, and contains no UrlData.

The built-in routing system will always assume that the URL represents a file path. The only time a default document comes into play is when the system has already determined that a/xyz.cshtml doesn't exists, so tries to establish if xyz is a folder containing a default document. If a/xyz/default.cshtml (or index.cshtml) doesn't exist, no further attempts are made to locate a default document while trying to match this particular URL to a file path.